# Show different 'height' for links on hover over with CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to do this with CSS only. I have an unordered list and some hyperlinked list items and I want to limit the width and height of the links (list items) to width:300px and height:1.5em.  So, no matter what the length of the links are, only up to 300px of the links will be showing and the rest will be hidden because of height limit and overflow:hidden. I want to show the rest of the link on mouse hover.

I can partially do this and hover over links shows the rest of the content BUT it also pushes down the content below it.

Is it possible, to show the rest of the content on mouseover WITHOUT pushing down the content below it?

Please see this fiddle 'http://jsfiddle.net/3VyaC/'

Comment: No, because content increased and height has been changed at the same time. Unless you'll set same height on element and it's hover state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks a little clunky, but it's close to the effect you're shooting for. Only changed your CSS:

```
body {font-family: arial; font-size: 0.8em;}

.news-entry ul {    
    list-style-type: none;  
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0 0 0 8px;  
    width: 300px;      
}

.news-entry li {
    border-top: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
    width:300px;
    height:1.5em;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}

.news-entry li a.itemtitle {    
    display: block; 
    width: 100%;    
    padding: 4px 0 3px 0;   
    line-height: 1.5em; 
    text-decoration: none;
}

.news-entry li:hover {
    color: #333;    
    background-color: #fafafa;
    overflow:visible;
    z-index:10;    
}

.news-entry li:hover a{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#fafafa;
    border:1px solid #555;      
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y3Vkt/

Might need to tweak the margins when the link changes to absolute position, there's a 1-2px glitch.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There would not be a way to do this. The only way you could actually do that is by setting `position: absolute;` but that would make the link sit on top of the next one. So to basically answer your question, there is not a way to do this with the width set as you have it.

Comment: Yah you can achieve that same effect by setting your `hover` `position` to `absolute`. However, like I mentioned, it will overlay on the other links just like the site you provided. To me that is just not very clean looking.